# SQL Server CE 4.0 database throws "No key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range"

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-ce

I'm a little stuck with an error that is a bit weird and I have never seen it until today. I have a primary key `PK__SessionsLog__0000000000000082` and when I'm trying to remove with this command:

```
alter table sessionslog 
    drop constraint PK__SessionsLog__0000000000000082
```

I get this error:

> No key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range

With no other information provided.

Does someone have a clue what is happening?

Other technical information:

- The SQL Server CE database version I'm using is 4.0
- The primary key does exist; I can list it with the following command:

  ```
  select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
  where table_name = 'sessionslog' and column_name = 'sessionid'
  ```
- The sessionslog was created using this following query,

  *CREATE TABLE SessionsLog(
        SessionID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        ReportFile IMAGE NULL,
        LogFile IMAGE NULL );*
- The table was in a database created on a Windows 8.1 O.S. I'm trying to do the drop on a Windows 7 due a migration.
- If I try drop the table it says the same thing: "No key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range".

Comment: I guess you are missing part of string when u copied the constraint

Comment: Are u using Temp tables by any chance with table create scripts ?

Comment: I don't think so, the value that "select CONSTRAINT_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where table_name='sessionslog' and column_name='sessionid' " gives me is PK__SessionsLog__0000000000000082

Comment: temp tables ? mmmm some time ago yes but not in the previous upate as far as I know.

Comment: It looks like `Sessionlog` is a temp table as name suggests, when u create temp table with primary key, it gives constraint value like `_0000..`

Comment: @BHouse  I think no, but let's suppose that session log is a tmp table... so how can I  drop a constraint in a tmp table ?

Comment: They are only active for that session, will get dropped automatically when u drop that session

Comment: @BHouse I can ensure that the table is not temporal. May is there some internal data that it tells that SessionsLog is a temporal table? I'm a bit confused XD.

Comment: Drop the table and give the PK a proper name when you recreate it.

Comment: @ErikEJ this can be a solution but I would like  as well as to other people) to know the root of this error. I suspect it happens due different the table was created on a Windows 8.1 and I'm trying to drop constraint on a windows 7

Comment: @ErikEJ if I try drop the table it says the same thing: "No key matching the described characteristics could be found within the current range”